# How am I logged on as a user, when the user doesn't exist in "user accounts"

Tags: windows-7, windows, login, domain, user

I logged onto a Windows 7 machine with the username MDC.  When I do a "whoami" command it says cityfire\mdc,  which I assume means on user "mcd", on "cityfire" domain.  But if I look in "user accounts" there is no username "mdc".  I assumed it's because I'm logging on to a domain and the "mdc" profile is stored there, but I had no network connectivity at the time i logged in, so it seems the profile is in the local machine itself. So where is is the profile for this user and domain stored on the local machine.  There is a folder in Users, but I assume there somewhere else I could look at and edit the user profile?  Thanks

Comment: Did you get a Temporary Profile message when you logged in? You can check in `C:\Users` for the existence of a TEMP user folder to verify this.

Comment: Let me get this straight, is this a domain computer or a home computer?

Answer (score 0):

You're basically right, there's no user in User Accounts because Windows was using its cached domain information to allow you to log in without the network.  The folder you see in Users sounds like it's cityfire\mdc's folder.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up terms:

- The **profile** – personal files, AppData, registry hive – is stored in `C:\Users\mdc`.

  The profile can be entirely local (default mode), or roaming (copied from server on logon, copied back on logout), or it could be local with folder redirection (where the main directory is local but things like Desktop are actually hosted on a SMB file share).
- The **account** – information such as the username, SID, password, access rights – is stored on CITYFIRE's Active Directory servers.

  Some domains let you browse the directory using "AD Domains and Users" from [RSAT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520); you could probably see your account there if the security isn't too tight.

  (Though if the domain is NT4, not AD, you'll need `usrmgr.exe` instead.)