# Windows 7 cached domain/user information

Tags: windows-7, windows, login, domain, users

In reference to the question I asked earlier.  [How am I logged on as a user, when the user doesn't exist in "user accounts"](https://superuser.com/q/976317/500183)
Where does windows keep its cached domain\user information.  I logged on to a pc that was not connected to a network.  I found that the username I used was not in "user accounts"  but there was already a folder for it in the user directories and it was assigned to a domain.  So, where does windows reference the information it needs to log the user on and assign it to a domain?  Thanks.